# Cannot retrieve foreign key ID

Tags: django

I am building an application that allows a user to create a scenario, then create associated emails, t, calls and trades to the scenario.

There is a 1:many relationship with the scenario and the communications. The issue I am having is I want the user to be able to click the scenario, it then shows the filtered list of communications, each communication source is a tab. The way I am filtering the communication is based on the id of the foreign key on the object. However if there is no entry for the datasource I receive a "no reverse match" because I am using the scenario id from the first object and that doesnt exist if there is no communication for that scenario.

I am stumped on what the best way to do this, besides removing tabs which I like.

Please let me know if I am missing anything, I am relatively new to programming and very new to Django.

## models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Scenario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenarios:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Email(models.Model):
    scenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    recipient_email = models.EmailField()
    sender_email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False, max_length=256)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False,  max_length=2048)
    # timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    # updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenarios:email-index')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sender_email + ' ' + self.recipient_email + ' ' + self.subject


class InstantMessage(models.Model):
    NETWORKS = (
        ('Yahoo', 'Yahoo'),
        ('MSN', 'MSN'),
        ('Skype', 'Skype')
    )
    scenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    network = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, choices=NETWORKS)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    starttime = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    endtime = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    participant1 = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    participant2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    chatcsv = models.FileField(upload_to='chatfiles')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenarios:im-index')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Network=" + self.network + " Description:" + self.description



class VoiceCall(models.Model):
    DIRECTION = (
        ('outbound', 'Outbound'),
        ('inbound', 'Inbound')
    )

    scenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    direction = models.CharField(choices=DIRECTION, null=False, blank=False, default="Outbound", max_length=15)
    starttime = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    endtime = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    traderid = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False, null=False)
    diallednumber = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cli = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nameofcaller = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    nameofline = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    wavfile = models.FileField(upload_to='voice')
    transcript = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='voice')
    bagofwords = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='voice')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenarios:call-index')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description


class Trade(models.Model):
    scenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tradeprefix = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=False, blank=False)
    trader = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    sales = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    counterpartyid = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    counterpartyname = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    brokerid = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    brokername = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    isevent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenarios:trade-index')

    # def __unicode__(self):
    #     return self.description


class Mobile(models.Model):
    scenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    displayname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
    tonumber = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    fromnumber = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False, max_length=1024)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenarios:mobile-index')
```

## views.py

```
  class IMScenarioList(generic.ListView):
    model = InstantMessage
    template_name = 'scenarios/im_filtered.html'
    context_object_name = 'scenario_ims'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return InstantMessage.objects.filter(scenario=self.kwargs['pk'])


class CallScenario(generic.ListView):
    model = VoiceCall
    template_name = 'scenarios/call_filtered.html'
    context_object_name = 'scenario_calls'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return VoiceCall.objects.filter(scenario=self.kwargs['pk'])


class MobileScenario(generic.ListView):
    model = Mobile
    template_name = 'scenarios/mobile_filtered.html'
    context_object_name = 'scenario_mobiles'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Mobile.objects.filter(scenario=self.kwargs['pk'])


class TradeScenario(generic.ListView):
    model = Trade
    template_name = 'scenarios/trades_filtered.html'
    context_object_name = 'trades'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Trade.objects.filter(scenario=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/email/$', views.EmailScenarioList.as_view(), name='email-scenario'),

    # Instant Messages
    url(r'^im/$', views.IMList.as_view(), name='im-index'),
    url(r'^im/add/$', views.IMCreate.as_view(), name='im-create'),
    url(r'^im/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.IMUpdate.as_view(), name='im-update'),
    url(r'^im/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.IMDelete.as_view(), name='im-delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/im/$', views.IMScenarioList.as_view(), name='im-scenario'),

    # Voice Calls
    url(r'^calls/$', views.CallList.as_view(), name='call-index'),
    url(r'calls/add/$', views.CallCreate.as_view(), name='call-create'),
    url(r'^calls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.CallUpdate.as_view(), name='call-update'),
    url(r'^calls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.CallDelete.as_view(), name='call-delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/voice/$', views.CallScenario.as_view(), name='call-scenario'),

    # trades
    url(r'^trades/$', views.TradeList.as_view(), name='trade-index'),
    url(r'^trades/add/$', views.TradeCreate.as_view(), name='trade-create'),
    url(r'^trades/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.TradeUpdate.as_view(), name='trade-update'),
    url(r'^trades/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.TradeDelete.as_view(), name='trade-delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/trade/$', views.TradeScenario.as_view(), name='trade-scenario'),

    # mobile
    url(r'^mobile/$', views.MobileList.as_view(), name='mobile-index'),
    url(r'^mobile/add/$', views.MobileCreate.as_view(), name='mobile-create'),
    url(r'^mobile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.MobileUpdate.as_view(), name='mobile-update'),
    url(r'^mobile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.MobileDelete.as_view(), name='mobile-delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/mobile/$', views.MobileScenario.as_view(), name='mobile-scenario'),
```

## Templates

## trade_index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter tablesorter-bootstrap">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="first-name filter-select" data-placeholder="Select a Scenario">Scenario</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Trade Prefix</th>
                    <th>Trader</th>
                    <th>Sales</th>
                    <th>Counterparty ID</th>
                    <th class="first-name filter-select" data-placeholder="Select Counterparty">Counterparty Name</th>
                    <th>Broker ID</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="first-name filter-select" data-placeholder="Select Broker">Broker Name</th>
                    <th class="first-name filter-select" data-placeholder="IsEvent">IsEvent</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for  trade in trades %}
                  <tr>
                <td data-toggle="tooltip" title="Description: {{trade.scenario.description}}">{{trade.scenario}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{trade.tradeprefix}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.trader}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.sales}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.counterpartyid}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.counterpartyname}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.brokerid}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{trade.brokername}}</td>
                    <td>{{trade.isevent}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{% url 'scenarios:trade-update' trade.id %}">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" />
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </td>

                    <td><form action="{% url 'scenarios:trade-delete' pk=trade.id %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="call_id" value="{{ trade.id}}"/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete {{trade.description}}?')">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" />
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <a href="{% url 'scenarios:trade-create' %}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" />

                </button>
            </a> Add Trade
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"  value="Back" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" />
            </button>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

## trades_filtered.html

```
{% extends 'scenarios/trade_index.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% with trades|first as first_trade %}
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'scenarios:trade-scenario' pk=first_trade.scenario.id %}">trades</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'scenarios:email-scenario' pk=first_trade.scenario.id %}">emails</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'scenarios:im-scenario' pk=first_trade.scenario.id %}">instant messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'scenarios:call-scenario' pk=first_trade.scenario.id %}">voice</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'scenarios:mobile-scenario' pk=first_trade.scenario.id %}">mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
{% endwith %}
        {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What are your models?

Comment: Hi Michael l, sorry I didnt post that. Just edited with the models.
Thanks,Chris

Comment: Your scenario is rather complicated. It's difficult for someone not intimately familiar with it to visualize what is happening. Try coming up with a minimal example that just illustrates the design problem you are trying to solve. With just a few simple models and views. Often, the task of coming up with a simple example will show me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now in `trades_filtered.html` you take the ID of a given `scenario` and use that ID to manually construct your five URLs. If it were me, I'd use a custom model method to determine whether or not we need to generate a URL first.

```
class Scenario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def generate_trade_url(self):
        if self.trade_set.exists():
            return reverse('scenarios:trade-scenario', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
        return None

    def generate_email_url(self):
        ...
```

You would need one method like this for each URL you want to generate. You can this use this logic either in the view (preferable) or in your template (simpler but slower) to dynamically generate your URLs only when they are valid.

EDIT: I just looked at this answer a second time. I included `null=False` in the `name` field definition because it was in the original, but be aware that it doesn't actually do anything useful on a `CharField`. Django doesn't use null values for those fields, instead storing them as `''` (empty string).

Comment: This sounds like an idea.. I need to now figure out how to use the method in a view . Something at this moment I have no idea how to do. But baby steps .... will give it a bash.

Comment: I would be happy to help, but an extended discussion in the comments is typically frowned upon. You are looking to add context data to a class-based view, this will get you started: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context If you run into trouble with that, please feel free to open a new question and tag me (I will try to come answer), or message me through my website at http://souldeux.com.

Comment: I most likely did this wrong. I did go down this road and it worked fine, a lot extra code. Eventually I ended up having to use an iframe along with the nav-pills.. ended up reverting the code back to using a iframe example:       `<li><a href="{% url 'scenarios:trade-scenario' pk=scenario.id %}" target="iframe_a">trades</a></li>`. This works fine.